Undefined reference when linking to mingw libraries
I have installed MinGW and CMake with MSYS2 UCRT64.
I have repeatedly failed to build a GUI application using several libraries: IUP and NAppGUI.
All the problems are of the type, "undefined reference to XXX" when linking. XXX is a function from system libraries (ex: GdipFree, __imp___argc, _setjmp, __imp_GetThemeFont).
I have tried reinstalling MinGW from scoop and still failed to build. I also tried to build using Ninja instead of Make, and failed too.
Currently trying to finish a project at college, any help is appreciated.
NAppGUI build log:
[main] Building folder: nappgui_test 
[main] Configuring project: nappgui_test 
[proc] Executing command: C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\cmake.EXE --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\g++.exe -SC:/Users/avila/nappgui_test -Bc:/Users/avila/nappgui_test/build -G "MinGW Makefiles"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
[cmake]   Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
[cmake]   CMake.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
[cmake]   CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] Found NAppGUI at 'C:/Users/avila/nappgui'
[cmake]    Version: 1.4.2.5131
[cmake]    Linker: static
[cmake] -- - [OK] napphello: Desktop application
[cmake] -- Configuring done (0.2s)
[cmake] -- Generating done (0.1s)
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/avila/nappgui_test/build
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: chcp
[proc] Executing command: C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\cmake.EXE --build c:/Users/avila/nappgui_test/build --config Debug --target all -j 10 --
[build] [ 33%] Building C object hello/CMakeFiles/napphello.dir/napphello.c.obj
[build] [ 66%] Building RC object hello/CMakeFiles/napphello.dir/res.rc.obj
[build] [100%] Linking CXX executable ..\Debug\bin\napphello.exe
[build] C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/avila/nappgui/lib/libosgui.a(osdrawctrl.cpp.obj): in function `osdrawctrl_font':
[build] C:/Users/avila/nappgui_src/src/osgui/win/osdrawctrl.cpp:57:(.text+0x1007e): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemeFont'
[build] C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/avila/nappgui/lib/libosgui.a(osdrawctrl.cpp.obj): in function `i_sort_size':
[build] C:/Users/avila/nappgui_src/src/osgui/win/osdrawctrl.cpp:211:(.text+0x104bd): undefined reference to `__imp_GetThemePartSize'
[build] C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/avila/nappgui/lib/libosgui.a(osgui_win.cpp.obj): in function `osgui_start_imp':
[build] C:/Users/avila/nappgui_src/src/osgui/win/osgui_win.cpp:459:(.text+0x115aa): undefined reference to `__imp_InitCommonControlsEx'
[build] C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/avila/nappgui_src/src/osgui/win/osgui_win.cpp:476:(.text+0x11659): undefined reference to `GdiplusStartup'
[build] C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/avila/nappgui/lib/libosgui.a(osgui_win.cpp.obj): in function `osgui_finish_imp':
[build] C:/Users/avila/nappgui_src/src/osgui/win/osgui_win.cpp:592:(.text+0x11aa2): undefined reference to `GdiplusShutdown'
.
.
.
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [hello\CMakeFiles\napphello.dir\build.make:115: Debug/bin/napphello.exe] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:97: hello/CMakeFiles/napphello.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:135: all] Error 2
[proc] The command: C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\cmake.EXE --build c:/Users/avila/nappgui_test/build --config Debug --target all -j 10 -- exited with code: 2
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:04.892
[build] Build finished with exit code 2

IUP build log:
[main] Building folder: iup_test 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\cmake.EXE --build c:/Users/avila/iup_test/build --config Debug --target all --
[build] [1/1 100% :: 0.335] Linking C executable iup_test.exe
[build] FAILED: iup_test.exe 
[build] C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\cc.exe -g  CMakeFiles/iup_test.dir/main.c.obj -o iup_test.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libiup_test.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  C:/Users/avila/iup_test/iup/libiup.a  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
[build] C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/avila/iup_test/iup/libiup.a(iupwin_open.o):iupwin_open.c:(.text+0x160): undefined reference to `__imp_InitCommonControlsEx'
.
.
.
[build] C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/avila/iup_test/iup/libiup.a(iupwindows_main.o):iupwindows_main.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__imp___argc[.refptr.__imp___argc]+0x0): undefined reference to `__imp___argc'
[proc] The command: C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\cmake.EXE --build c:/Users/avila/iup_test/build --config Debug --target all -- exited with code: 1
[build] C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/avila/iup_test/iup/libiup.a(iupwindows_main.o):iupwindows_main.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__imp___argv[.refptr.__imp___argv]+0x0): undefined reference to `__imp___argv'
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:00.428
[build] Build finished with exit code 1

Built and tried to link IUP and NAppGUI example app, but failed. I followed the steps from NAppGUI and IUP tutorial.

Code starting with main provides argc and argv, but not when starting with WinMain. Something in your code is confused about console vs GUI.

Everything starting with __imp_ is imported from some DLL, and you have to link with the corresponding .lib file. For example InitCommonControlsEx says that it is part of Comctl32.lib.

@stark the argc and argv was from the following example: https://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/
*Sorry, the web is one big link. It was from the Hello World section from IUP's tutorial

@BoP Can you elaborate on it? Is there any readings for the topic? I am pretty confused about the .a libraries that comes with MinGW and the .dll in system32. I thought the build system that comes with IUP and NAppGUI should've handled the system libraries' linking.

I don't know what those build systems do. I can see that the command line lists lots of libraries to link in -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 etc, but there is no -lcomctl32. Or -lUxTheme for the Theme-functions.
